# How to call a function every 1-3 second?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to write a mini-game using canvas, one of the task is to create "bug" object entering the scene between every 1-3 seconds. I did try functions like setTimeOut,setInterval but I couldn't get it right. Here is my attempt

```
  bugs =[];
  function addBug(){
     var bug = createBug();
     bugs.push(bug);
  }

  function createRandomNumber(max){
     return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
  };

  var enterBug = setInterval(addBug,createRandomNumber(10)*1000);
```

currently I got it spawning at constant rate but don't know how to change it to every 1-3.Any suggestion? thanks in advance.

Comment: @CupawnTae, you're right. Sorry for the brain fart.

Comment: @JonathanM and yet someone upvoted it :)

Comment: @CupawnTae, LOL! Fool some of the people all the time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you are only setting the rate once at initial `setInterval` call.  You would likely need to use setTimeout like this:

```
...
function addBug(){
   ...
   bugTimeout = setTimeout(addBug, createRandomNumber(10)*1000);
}
...
bugTimeout = setTimeout(addBug, createRandomNumber(10)*1000);
```

You also may think about your random number generation if you want to get more randomness. Right now you can only get exact second values 1-10 since you are multiplying by 1000 to convert to seconds AFTER the random generation is done.  If you want something more random you might use:

```
function createRandomNumber(maxSeconds){
    minSeconds = 1;
    if (maxSeconds < minSeconds) {
        maxSeconds = minSeconds;
    }
    interval = maxSeconds - minSeconds;
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * interval) + minSeconds) * 1000;
};
```

You of course would not need to multiply by 1000 anymore when setting timeout.

```
bugTimeout = setTimeout(addBug, createRandomNumber(10))
```

Comment: yeah, setTimeout seems like a solutions for me as well. spelling? Mike was just hurrying

Comment: @sbedulin clearly, but that doesn't seem like a reason not to point it out. Would have edited it myself but didn't want to conflict if Mike was also updating.

Comment: @Mike Brant Thanks for the help, it seems working for the most part , however sometime it spawn multiple bug at once, can we avoid this, that allow only one bug enter the scene every 1-3?

Comment: @user97919 There is nothing here that should cause you to spawn multiple bugs at once (i.e. created at same time).